# Comments containing long words causes comments to run off the edge of the screen

Tags: bug, mobile-web

The first post I've seen this on is https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/31807/16141.

> [image]

**Note** how the text in the comments runs off the right hand side of the page.

This seems to be due to the programmers.SE link in one of the comments, and might need some `break-word` styling...

What makes this even more of a problem is that the page is fixed to the width of my screen, so I can't scroll horizontally to get the rest of the comments.

Comment: Comment withareallyreallyreallylongwordthatwillcausethecommentsofftheendofthepageonmobile